# to open an element individually on click of an option

Tags: jquery

i want a list to open when i click on an option of a  element. but i want that list to be opened individually for each option, but one at a time. i mean, when i click on option1, a list1 appears, then i click on option2 and list 1 disappears and list2 opens, but in the same fashion. i used this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".select-prod option").each(function(){
        $(this).click(function(){
            //  alert("sdd");
                $(this).parent().next("ul.suggestedprod").fadeIn(800);
            });         
        });
    });
```

html:

```
<select class="form-control select-prod">
    <option>Aviva Freedom Life Advantage</option>
    <option>Aviva Freedom Life Advantage(Oct 2013)</option>
    <option>Aviva iGrowth</option>
</select>

  <ul class="suggestedprod">
  <li class="list-unstyled">Suggested policies similar to this one:</li>

    <li><a href="#">Aviva Live Smart</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Aviva Live Smart(Oct 2013)</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Aviva New Freedom Life Plan</a></li>
  </ul>
```

What is happening is that `ul.suggestedprod` appears on selection of any option i click for thr first time, then it does not fade in on the second one. i tries `.change()` instead of .click but it did not work. here is fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZZL62/3/

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you using `.each()`?

Comment: `option` doesn't fire events. `select` does.

Comment: Is that what you're looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/ZZL62/7/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a list of class list-unstyled for every option, you can change your javascript to something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".select-prod").change(function(){
        //hide all existing
        $("ul.suggestedprod").hide(); 

        //show only the nth list for this option
        $("ul.suggestedprod:nth(" + this.selectedIndex + ")").fadeIn(800);
    });
});
```

See the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZZL62/6/

Answer (score 0):

You have some problems in your code.

1. `option` doesn't fire events. The `select` is the one that does.
2. You don't need to use `.each()`, as your selector will bring up a collection anyway.

**ONE SOLUTION**

Assuming that your HTML markup will follow the structure below (your `uls` will be placed in the same sequence as your `options`), this should work:

```
<select class="form-control select-prod">
    <option>Product1</option>
    <option>Product2</option>
    <option>Product3</option>
</select>
<ul class="suggestedprod">
    <li class="list-unstyled">Suggested policies similar to this one (1):</li>
    <li><a href="#">policy1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">policy2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Policy3</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul class="suggestedprod">
    <li class="list-unstyled">Suggested policies similar to this one (2):</li>
    <li><a href="#">policy1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">policy2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Policy3</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul class="suggestedprod">
    <li class="list-unstyled">Suggested policies similar to this one (3):</li>
    <li><a href="#">policy1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">policy2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Policy3</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

...

```
$(function() {
    // Starts by showing the first one.
    // :eq(n) selects the item with index equals n in the collection.
    $("ul.suggestedprod:eq(0)").fadeIn(800);

    $(".select-prod").on("change", function () {
        $this = this;

        // Hide all that are shown now.
        // Wait for the fadeOut to finish its work before showing the selected.
        $("ul.suggestedprod")
            .filter(function(){ return !$(this).is(":hidden"); })
            .fadeOut(800, function() {
                // Show the selected.
                // Which is the ul with index equals to the option selected.
                $("ul.suggestedprod:eq(" + $this.selectedIndex + ")").fadeIn(800);
            });
        });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZZL62/8/)

**ANOTHER SOLUTION**

As I'm expecting you to give your `options` values, this would also work:

```
<select class="form-control select-prod">
    <option value="1" selected="selected">Product1</option>
    <option value="2">Product2</option>
    <option value="3">Product3</option>
</select>
<ul class="suggestedprod" data-myval="1">
    <li class="list-unstyled">Suggested policies similar to this one (1):</li>
    <li><a href="#">policy1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">policy2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Policy3</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul class="suggestedprod" data-myval="2">
    <li class="list-unstyled">Suggested policies similar to this one (2):</li>
    <li><a href="#">policy1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">policy2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Policy3</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul class="suggestedprod" data-myval="3">
    <li class="list-unstyled">Suggested policies similar to this one (3):</li>
    <li><a href="#">policy1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">policy2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Policy3</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

...

```
$(function() {
    var sel = $(".select-prod").val();   

    // Starts by showing the first one.
    $("ul.suggestedprod[data-myval=" + sel + "]").fadeIn(800);

    $(".select-prod").on("change", function () {
        sel = $(".select-prod").val();

        // Hide all that are shown now.
        $("ul.suggestedprod")
            .filter(function(){ return !$(this).is(":hidden"); })
            .fadeOut(800, function() {
                // Show the selected.
                $("ul.suggestedprod[data-myval=" + sel + "]").fadeIn(800);
            });
        });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZZL62/9/)

References:

[jQuery .eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)

[jQuery .fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/)

[jQuery .fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/)

[jQuery .filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

[jQuery .data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/)